# Convert inline function to sym in Matlab R2010b

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to convert an inline function to sym in matlab R2010b but it doesn't work. In matlab 2008 worked well. Here the code:

```
in = inline('t^2');
syms t real
sym(in);
??? Error using ==> sym.sym>tomupad at 2178
Conversion to 'sym' from 'inline' is not possible.

Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.sym at 111
                S.s = tomupad(x,'');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `inline`, you can use an anonymous function via a function handle:

```
f = @(t) t.^2;
syms t
F = sym(f);
```

which should give you the same inline functionality/portability.

Answer (score 0):

Using http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33025

```
in = inline('t^2');
f0 = inline2sym(in);

EDU>> f0

t^2

EDU>> syms t
EDU>> diff(f0,t)

ans =

2*t
```